# loader constraint violation error when adding maven dependency in target defination

Tags: maven, xtext, m2eclipse, tycho, eclipse-pde

[image: Error resolving target definition]

I am trying to add third party libraries in target definition of an xtext project. Could you please provide some hints about the probable cause for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the next version of xtext 2.28